# Searching for files which was created at certain date

Tags: windows-7, date-time, file-search

Is it possible to find files which was created at certain date? I don't remember file name, but I know date when it was created. I am using windows 7.

Comment: You should state which operating system you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the Windows OS, there's an excellent free/open-source Norton Commander clone that can do this:

FAR Manager
  http://www.farmanager.com/

In the search feature (press Alt-F7), you can turn on "Use filter" then define a new filter through the "Filter" option.  From within the Filter menu, press "Insert" to create a new filter and you will be presented with a dialogue box that allows you specify a creation timestamp, modified timestamp, etc.

If you're using Unix/Linux, there's a similar tool called Midnight Commander which I'm pretty sure has these types of search features available too.

Answer (score 4):

Open an explore window, browse to the root of your HD (or a sub folder of you think you know where the file might be within your HD) and enter 'datecreated:‎3/‎1/‎2011' in the search box [replace 3/1/2011 with the appropriate date].  This will return any file/folder modified on the date indicated.

Comment: You don’t have to manually enter the date; just click on the search box or press F3, then click the *date modified* button, and use the calendar control.

Comment: The question is regarding creation date rather than modified date, which does not by default show in the search box drop down tips.